# iCloud Documents and Desktop empty - macOS High Sierra

Tags: mac, icloud

I logged out of my iCloud account. Now I logged back in, and the Desktop is empty, and so is the Documents folder.

If I check online, all my files are still there. But they are not showing on my computer, running macOS High Sierra.

I have tried signing out again. In iCloud settings, I have checked Desktop and Documnet Folders to check that it syncs.

How do I get the contents of Desktop and Documents to sync to my Mac?

Answer (score 5):

I discovered, that you need to give it some time to restore the Desktop & Documents info from iCloud back to your Mac. If you keep signing back out, you just start the process all over again. Make sure you are connected to Wifi, and walk away. Check it in a few hours or tomorrow.